# position div center page

Tags: html, position

Can anyone tell me why my icon in div id="combinedClasp" is not centering on the page?

[Page here](http://www.test25.net/gems/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=14&Itemid=126)

I have set the margin-left & margin-right to auto. I have also played around with positioning to absolute and relative, but it does not go where it needs to.

If I set to position-relative and give it a "left" value, I can line it up where it needs to be, but that's just for my screen, on a different screen it would probably be out again.

Any help would be great...

Comment: Where do you want it to appear? Inside the necklace?

Comment: Yes, but Grimm got it! Positioned correct now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the margins, set a width of 100% and add `text-align: center;`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Grim, this worked nicely! I don't know why I didn't think of that :( Only one thing, I plan on expanding the thumbnail images to come further down the page so also had to use an "x-index: 3;" on thumbnail div to make sure they display on top of the "combinedClasp" div, otherwise I would not be able to select the images that are behind that div. Cheers for your help...!

Answer (score 0):

It is because that div is positioned absolutely so no matter what the margin's are it will always retain it's position set with: top, right, bottom, left.

You should set the left attribute to 733px

CSS:

```
#combinedClasp
{
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 331px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 733px;
}
```

Comment: This won't work I'm afraid, might look ok on your screen but not on others. I don't like positioning things from left or right with pixels, they can show up in different places depending on browser and resolution settings. Thanks for the advice anyway though, but Grim's answer sorted! BTW, needs to be absolutely positioned to make it show on top of the other div.